# Доступ к элементам коллекции

Tags: java

Коллекции, которые позволяют осуществить доступ к произвольному элементу за константное время? Я знаю про ArrayList. А еще?

Comment: А что мешает почитать javadoc в котором каждая коллекция расписана?

Comment: @Viacheslav, думаю, проще ознакомится с основными структурами данных вообще, а не в частностях. Тогда и проблем таких не будет.

Answer (score 2):

- HashSet — за константу
- TreeSet — за
     логарифм от количества элементов, что
     тоже неплохо.